# Full definition of .cabal file syntax

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have googled extensively, and while I can find many examples of cabal files as well as good tutorials, I would like to have a proper grammar definition for the .cabal file format.  Alas, I have not been able to find it.  The more recent cabal documentation only mentions that its file format is backwards compatible -- with no links to the 'original' format with which it is compatible!  Not useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

[Distribution.PackageDiscription](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.2/docs/html/libraries/Cabal/Distribution-PackageDescription.html)

Answer (score 15):

> a proper grammar definition for the .cabal file format.

The grammar is defined by [its parser](https://github.com/ghc/packages-Cabal/blob/d5e2bafe3f2d0a0a826205efaa168cf1b558d932/Cabal/Distribution/PackageDescription/Parse.hs#L639). I don't know of a formal specification.

Comment: It certainly is *an* answer.  I may even be forced to accept it as 'the' answer.  Unfortunate.

Comment: If a formal grammar existed there is no reason the developers would not have included it along with the sources, hence the parser is very likely the closest thing to a grammar that you will find.

Answer (score 1):

The list of the fields, whether they are required or not, and what goes in them is here https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-properties.

Not the most obvious of places, I must admit.